# On equation $exp [X,Y]=[exp X,exp Y]$ on a Lie group and its Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is a  classification of all Lie groups $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$  with the following equality $$exp [X,Y]=[exp X,exp Y]$$
for all $X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}$? Is there a non Abelian example?

Comment: Beware that there are several conventions for the group commutator, and your question may be sensitive to the choice of convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the BCH formula: it shows that every 2-step nilpotent Lie group satisfies this (assuming the group commutator is defined as $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, or as $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$).

(Continue with the convention $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$.)

> Actually, a Lie group satisfies this condition ($\exp$ intertwines commutators) if and only if its Lie algebra is 2-step nilpotent.

Indeed, the BCH formula yields, writing $x=\exp(X)$ and $y=\exp(Y)$, the Taylor expansion around zero:
$$\log([x,y])=[X,Y]+\frac12[X+Y,[X,Y]]+O((\|X\|+\|Y\|)^4).$$

Hence if the given equality holds, we deduce that $[X+Y,[X,Y]]$ for all $X,Y$. By homogeneity, we deduce $[X,[X,Y]]=0$ for all $X,Y$, and then writing $X=X'+Z'$ we deduce $[X,[Y,Z]]=0$ for all $X,Y,Z$, that is, the Lie algebra is 2-step nilpotent.

Certainly we reach the same conclusion with the commutator convention $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. While with the convention $y^{-1}x^{-1}yx$ or $yxy^{-1}x^{-1}$, we obtain by expansion at degree 2 that the given equality implies that the Lie algebra is abelian.

Comment: I  am sorry if my question is elementary: Should not we care about convergence in CBH formula?Moreover did you applied CBH formula twist(two time) when we are considering $exp(X)exp(Y)exp(-X)exp(-Y)$?

Comment: Actually I used the BCH formula in the weakest sense, i.e., as a Taylor expansion, and only used the first degree terms. Indeed things are even better since the BCH formula converges around zero, which I don't need.  Yes, for the group commutator I use it even three times.

Comment: what about if we   consider the same  formula in a  $C^*$  algebra? Is there an  example of  a  non commutative  $C^*$  algebra  which satisfy that formula?

Comment: Assume that a discrete group is a 2 step nilpotent. Does its reduced group $C^*$ algebra satisfy the identity under consideration?

Comment: These are other question, unrelated to Lie algebras.

Comment: ... if $G$ is nilpotent and not virtually abelian then its group algebra $\mathbf{C}[G]$ is not PI (indeed $G$ has finite-dim irreducible reps of arbitrary large degree).

Comment: I just find a paper "Fourier transform on 2-step lie group" its materials remind me of your very interesting answer. Thanks again for your answer!